# javascript - get row with max value in multi dimesion array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like

```
var arr = [ [1, 4, 5],
            [2, 6, 7],
            [3, 3, 9]]
```

I would like to get the row which has max value in column 2, so in this example row 2. How can I do this in javascript?

Edit: I can do it using a for loop which iterates over all rows and have a temp max variable to keep track of the max. But I was hoping for a more efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try something ? Like for example iterate over the array ?

Comment: Yes I can do it using a for loop which iterates over all rows and have a temp max variable to keep track of the max. But I was hoping for a more efficient way

Comment: That's the most efficient way. Other ones are just sweeter.

Comment: What would you like to have happen in the case of a tie?

Comment: @Will in case of a tie, the last found element will be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, iterating and keeping a temporary max variable is probably the most efficient way of doing it, but if you want a way that looks more pleasing, you can try something like:

```
var col2 = arr.map(function (elem) {
    return elem[1]; //to get all the column 2 values
});

var index = col2.indexOf(Math.max.apply(this, col2));
```

Edit: If you want to use the index of the last found element in case of a tie, use

`col2.lastIndexOf(Math.max.apply(this, col2));`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can out better plain loop version, but you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this

```
var arr = [ [1, 4, 5], [2, 6, 7], [3, 3, 9]], col = 1;

var best = arr.reduce(function(tillNow, current) {
    if (tillNow.best < current[col]) {
        tillNow.best = current[col];
        tillNow.row  = current;
    }
    return tillNow;
}, {best:0, row:[]});

console.log(best.row);    # [ 2, 6, 7 ]
console.log(best);        # { best: 6, row: [ 2, 6, 7 ] }
```

Reduce function accepts the till now value as the first parameter and the current element as the second parameter.

For the first element, parameters will be like this

```
tillNow : {best:0, row:[]} : current: [1, 4, 5]
```

We compare `current`'s indented column with `tillNow.best`. If current's is bigger than `tillNow`, the best element and the current row will be set in `tillNow` and that will be returned which will be fed back into the `reduce`'s next iteration as `tillNow`. So, in our case, on the second iteration, values change like this

```
tillNow : {best:4, row: [1, 4, 5]} : current: [2, 6, 7]
```

And on third iteration,

```
tillNow : {best:6, row: [2, 6, 7]} : current: [3, 3, 9]
```

And finally the result will be

```
{ best: 6, row: [ 2, 6, 7 ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

This example returns runs [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over over each row and returns an array with the each row's number from the nominated column. It then returns the **index** of the highest number in that array.

```
function findRowForMaxInCol(arr, col) {
  var column = arr.map(function(el) { return el[col]; });
  var highest = Math.max.apply(null, column);
  return column.indexOf(highest);
}

console.log(findRowForMaxInCol(arr, 1)); // 1
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/zbQ3M/).

Comment: You get the maximum _value_, but how to get the row in which it sits?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will give you the highest number:

```
var array = [[1, 4, 5],
            [2, 6, 7],
            [3, 3, 9]];
var bigNum = 0;
for(var i=0;i<array.length; i++){
    var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, array[i]);
    if(largest > bigNum) {
         bigNum = largest;   
    }
}
console.log(bigNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
var arr = [[1, 4, 5], [2, 6, 7], [3, 3, 9]],
    t;

$.each(arr, function(k, v){
    t = !t ? v[1] : (v[1] > t ? v[1] : t);
});

console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
var col2 = [];
var max = 0;

$.each(arr, function(i, val){
    col2.push(val[1]);
})

max = Math.max.apply( Math, col2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterating through the array and checking if the second element is largest. The variable `large` will contain the row `i` and the largest value `e`.

```
var arr = [ [1, 4, 5],
        [2, 6, 7],
        [3, 3, 9]],
    large = {i:0, e: 0};  // i: row, e: largest elem
arr.map(function (a, idx) {
    if (a[1] > large.e) { 
        large.e = a[1];
        large.i = idx;
    }
});
console.log(large);  // {i: 1, e: 6}. row: 1 and element 6.
```

Comment: returns (0, 0) if array is []

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing the problem: find the element in an array which has the maximum 'f(x)':

```
var findMax = function(array, f){
    var element = null;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for (var i=0; i!=array.length; ++i){
        var value = f(array[i]);
        if (value > max){
            element=array[i];
            max=value;
        }
    };
    return element;
};
```

And apply the general algorithm to `rows` with a function returning the second element of the row:

```
var secondElement= function(row){ return row[1]; };

var max = findMax(rows, secondElement);
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/TKYtg/))